# X-axis not being properly shared in a dataframe plot where I have another overplot

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, data-science, astronomy

I want to overplot a transformed dataframe plot with another plot, but when I try to do that, y-axis seems to be shared properly, but there's some problem with the x-axis. The dataframe plot is plotted in the left, and the other plot in the right, even though they have similar x-values. Am I doing something wrong?
Here's a part of my code for good measure.

```
#----------------------
# Fetch single spectrum
plate = 1045
mjd = 52725
fiber = 403

spec = fetch_sdss_spectrum(plate, mjd, fiber)

sdss_jpas = jpas4[jpas3['JPAS_ID'].isin(['2470_9821'])]

sdss_jpas = sdss_jpas.set_index('JPAS_ID').T.div(100).iloc[::2, :]

#-----------------------------
# Plot the resulting spectrum
# plotting = tempframe.plot(marker = 'o', legend=False, ax = ax)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

ax.plot(spec.wavelength(), spec.spectrum, '-k',  lw=1) #the overplot on df

tempframe.plot(marker = 'o', legend=False, ax = ax)    #the df plot

ax.legend(['0.8', '1', '1.5', '3', '4', '6'])
ax.set_title('2470_9821')

ax.set_xlabel(r'$\lambda {(\rm \AA)}$')
ax.set_ylabel('Flux [1e$^{-17}$erg/s/cm$^2$/$\AA$]')
ax.set_title('Plate = %(plate)i, MJD = %(mjd)i, Fiber = %(fiber)i' % locals())

plt.show()
```

[What I get ][1] : What I want would be the top two images to coincide in a single frame.
![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVrAt.png

Comment: Is spec also a dataframe? If so, what are its columns?

Comment: It's a dataframe as well. But all I would need here are wavelength and spectrum.
I found some roundabout way around this, but the actual issue still remains that I can't overplot over a df plot.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine with the toy data below if you take out the parentheses in spec.wavelength().  Also get rid of your first ax.set_title() statement.

```
x_data = list(range(10))
y1 = [x+5 for x in x_data]
y2 = [x**2 for x in x_data]
y3 = [x**3 for x in x_data]

tempframe =pd.DataFrame({'x':x_data, 'linear':y1, 'quadratic':y2})
tempframe = tempframe.set_index('x')
spec =pd.DataFrame({'wavelength':x_data, 'specxtrum':y3})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot(spec.wavelength, spec.specxtrum, '-k',  lw=1, label = 'spectrum')
tempframe.plot(marker = 'o', ax = ax)

ax.set_xlabel(r'$\lambda {(\rm \AA)}$')
ax.set_ylabel('Flux [1e$^{-17}$erg/s/cm$^2$/$\AA$]')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]